# javascript addEventListener on two different variables in a loop -> first listener does not work

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

Only the buttonEndNumber eventlistener is triggered correctly. The `buttonStartNumber` is not doing anything.

```
function appendNumberButtons()
    {
        var xpathExpression = 'id("delform")/div/div/div/div/div/div'
        var xpathResult = document.evaluate(xpathExpression, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
    
        var buttonStartNumber
        var buttonEndNumber
        
        for ( var i=0 ; i < xpathResult.snapshotLength; i++ )
        {
            buttonStartNumber = document.createElement("input")
            buttonStartNumber.setAttribute('type', 'button')
            buttonStartNumber.setAttribute('value',"S"+i)
            //buttonStartNumber.addEventListener('click', function(i){ return function(I){alert(i)} }(i), false);
            listnerHelper(buttonStartNumber, i);
            
            
            buttonEndNumber = document.createElement("input")
            buttonEndNumber.setAttribute('type', 'button')
            buttonEndNumber.setAttribute('value',"E"+i)
            //buttonEndNumber.addEventListener('click', function(i){ return function(I){alert(i)} }(i), false);
            listnerHelper(buttonEndNumber, i);
                    
            xpathResult.snapshotItem(i).innerHTML += " -> "
            xpathResult.snapshotItem(i).appendChild(buttonStartNumber)
            xpathResult.snapshotItem(i).innerHTML += " - "
            xpathResult.snapshotItem(i).appendChild(buttonEndNumber)
        }
    }
```

Things I've tried:

An extra function `listenerHelper(object, i) -> nop buttonStartNumber`, `buttonEndNumber` as arrays with and without `listenerHelper(object, i) -> nop`

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did it worked after testing `buttonStartNumber.addEventListener('click', function(i){ return function(I){alert(i)} }(i), false);
`? Did you mistyped `listnerHelper` in your code?

Comment: The listnerHelper was just a typo id did not fix in the comment. After fiddling around for hours I commented the line xpathResult.snapshotItem(i).innerHTML += " - "
and everything start working. Wtf ?

Comment: Solution: textNode = document.createTextNode(" - ") 
xpathResult.snapshotItem(i).appendChild(textNode) Problem solved now thx Littm

Comment: Your welcome mate, I'm glad it worked for you ;)